# Warning when upgrade scripts?

Tags: magento2, column, upgradeschema

```
  if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.10', '<=')) {
            $installer = $setup;
            $installer->startSetup();

            // Get tutorial_simplenews table
            $tableName = $installer->getTable('blog_post');
            // Check if the table already exists
          if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) != true) {
            // Create tutorial_simplenews table



            $table = $installer->getConnection()
                ->newTable($tableName)
                ->addColumn(
                    'id',
                    Table::TYPE_INTEGER,                                    
                    [
                        'identity' => true,
                        'unsigned' => true,
                        'nullable' => false,
                        'primary' => true
                    ],
                    'ID'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'docid',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,   
                    255,                 
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'docid'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'order_status',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,                    
                    255,
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Order Status'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'order_code',
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,     
                    255,                                   
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Order Code'
                )
                  ->addColumn(
                    'order_id',                    
                    Table::TYPE_TEXT,    
                     255,                                    
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Order Id'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'created_at',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,                    
                    ['nullable' => false,'default' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TIMESTAMP_INIT_UPDATE],
                    'Created At'
                )
                ->addColumn(
                    'update_at',
                    Table::TYPE_DATETIME,                    
                    ['nullable' => false, 'default' => ''],
                    'Updated At'
                )
                ->setComment('dfdfd')
                ->setOption('type', 'InnoDB')
                ->setOption('charset', 'utf8');
            $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);           
        }
            $installer->endSetup();


        } 


Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given i  
  n /var/www/html/readyresale_beta/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Ddl/Table.php   
  on line 352
```

Answer (score 0):

**UpgradeSchema.php**

```
$installer = $setup;
$installer->startSetup();
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.10') < 0) {
    // Get module table
    $tableName = $installer->getTable('blog_post');

    // Check if the table already exists
    if ($installer->getConnection()->isTableExists($tableName) == true) {
        // Declare data
        $columns = array(
            'id' => array(
                'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'size' => null,
                'options' => array('nullable' => false, 'default' => ''),
                'comment' => 'Id',
            ),
            'docid' => array(
                'type' => Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                'size' => null,
                'options' => array('nullable' => true, 'default' => ''),
                'comment' => 'Docid',
            ),
            // Do the same for the other...
        );

        $connection = $installer->getConnection();
        foreach ($columns as $name => $definition) {
            $connection->addColumn($tableName, $name, $definition);
        }
    }
}
```

### Update

To add new table with attributes

```
$setup->startSetup();
if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.10') < 0)) {
    $installer = $setup;
    $installer->startSetup();

    $table = $installer->getConnection()
        ->newTable($installer->getTable('table_name'))
        ->addColumn(
      //...The attributes here (If you have many columns use the foreach solution above)
    );

    $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
    $installer->endSetup();
}
```

Comment: table is not inserted not showing any error after upgrade script

Comment: Which table ? the table is already exists, here you juste update it to add your new columns

Comment: no i am creating table and colukmn via upgradeschemea.php

Comment: Look my update please